# Alert popping up incrementally on updating data

Tags: jquery, object, dynamic, bootstrap-modal, unbind

I've a dynamic button to edit some data for an object. Now, once the data is updated successfully, I'm throwing an alert to the user, stating that it was successfully done.

However, when the user edits the same object 2nd time, it throws the same alert twice. Likewise, thrice when the same object is updated for the 3rd time and so on.

I believe, I need to unbind the click event on the dynamic button to fix this and ensure that alert pops-up only once each time the object is edited.

Also, please not that tool name and tool url are option fields by default but become mandatory if any one of tool name and tool url are filled out.

How do I unbind the click event on '.edit-btn' button in my code below?

```js
var myData = [{
  company: "ABC",
  url: "www.abc.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "CDE",
  url: "www.cde.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "DEF",
  url: "www.def.com",
  toolName: "reportTool",
  toolURL: "http://www.toolURL.com",
  type: "external"
}, {
  company: "EFG",
  url: "www.efg.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "FGH",
  url: "www.fgh.com",
  type: "external"
}];

$('#createData').click(function() {
  createDisplay();
});

function createDisplay() {
  $('.container').empty();
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
      $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
      obj.type == 'external' ? $('<br /><button>').addClass('edit-btn').text('Edit').attr({'data-toggle':'modal', 'data-target':'#updateData'}) : ''
      )
    )
  });
}

var objIndex;
$(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function(){

  objIndex = $(this).parents('.box').index();

  var $toolName = $('#newToolName');
  var $toolURL = $('#newToolUrl');
  var $toolInputs = $($toolName).add($toolURL);

  $toolInputs.on('change', function(e) {

    var toolName = $toolName.val();
    var toolURL = $toolURL.val();

    $toolInputs.prop('required', toolName || toolURL);

  });


    $('#updateForm').submit(function(e){
    var toolName = $toolName.val()
    var toolURL = $toolURL.val()

    var toolFilled = !!toolName && !!toolURL;
    var toolUnfilled = !toolName && !toolURL;

    if (toolFilled || toolUnfilled) {
      updateData(objIndex);
      return false;
    }
    return false;
    });
});

function updateData(index) {
  companyName = $('#companyName').val();
  companyUrl = $('#companyUrl').val();
  toolName = $('#newToolName').val();
  toolURL = $('#newToolUrl').val();
  var upObj = {
  company: companyName,
  url: companyUrl,
  toolName: toolName,
  toolURL: toolURL,
  type: 'external'
  }
  myData.splice(index, 1, upObj);
  console.log(myData[index]);
  createDisplay();
  alert('Data updated successfully!');
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

</div>

<button id="createData">Create divs</button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="updateData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
    </div>
    <form id="updateForm">
    <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyUrl">Website</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" required />
      </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolName">Tool Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newToolName" />
      </div>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolUrl">Tool URL</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="url" class="form-control" id="newToolUrl" />
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  <!-- Modal Footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add `$('#updateForm').off("submit")` before your `if (toolFilled || toolUnfilled)`

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the click event for a class like:

```
$(document).off('click', '.edit-btn');
```

It will `unbind` the previous event listener attached with `'.edit-btn'`

Comment: Where do I do that exactly in my code? I'm new to jQuery.

Comment: Put this code after the click event functionality completes. So that it can `unbind` further events

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.edit-btn` click event, you have the change event and the submit event inside it so the events bind each time you click the `.edit-btn`

```js
var myData = [{
  company: "ABC",
  url: "www.abc.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "CDE",
  url: "www.cde.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "DEF",
  url: "www.def.com",
  toolName: "reportTool",
  toolURL: "http://www.toolURL.com",
  type: "external"
}, {
  company: "EFG",
  url: "www.efg.com",
  type: "internal"
}, {
  company: "FGH",
  url: "www.fgh.com",
  type: "external"
}];

$('#createData').click(function() {
  createDisplay();
});

function createDisplay() {
  $('.container').empty();
  myData.forEach(function(obj) {
    $('.container').append(
      $('<div>').addClass('box').append(
        $('<label>').text('Company Website: '),
        $('<a>').addClass('compUrl').attr('href', obj.url).text(obj.company),
        obj.type == 'external' ? $('<br /><button>').addClass('edit-btn').text('Edit').attr({
          'data-toggle': 'modal',
          'data-target': '#updateData'
        }) : ''
      )
    )
  });
}


  objIndex = $(this).parents('.box').index();

  var $toolName = $('#newToolName');
  var $toolURL = $('#newToolUrl');
  var $toolInputs = $($toolName).add($toolURL);

  $toolInputs.on('change', function(e) {

    var toolName = $toolName.val();
    var toolURL = $toolURL.val();

    $toolInputs.prop('required', toolName || toolURL);

  });
  
  $('#updateForm').submit(function(e) {
    var toolName = $toolName.val()
    var toolURL = $toolURL.val()

    var toolFilled = !!toolName && !!toolURL;
    var toolUnfilled = !toolName && !toolURL;

    if (toolFilled || toolUnfilled) {
      updateData(objIndex);
      return false;
    }
    return false;
  });
  
function updateData(index) {
  companyName = $('#companyName').val();
  companyUrl = $('#companyUrl').val();
  toolName = $('#newToolName').val();
  toolURL = $('#newToolUrl').val();
  var upObj = {
    company: companyName,
    url: companyUrl,
    toolName: toolName,
    toolURL: toolURL,
    type: 'external'
  }
  myData.splice(index, 1, upObj);
  console.log(myData[index]);
  createDisplay();
  alert('Data updated successfully!');
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

</div>

<button id="createData">Create divs</button>
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="updateData" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="update-data" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
      </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Data</h4>
      </div>
      <form id="updateForm">
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyName">Company Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="companyUrl">Website</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="url" class="form-control" id="companyUrl" placeholder="Company URL" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolName">Tool Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newToolName" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="newToolUrl">Tool URL</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="url" class="form-control" id="newToolUrl" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```